# Using SecurityDisabler with Glass Mapper GlassView

Tags: security, glass-mapper

We have content that we want to display that is in an area of the site secured from anonymous access. The idea is to show a group of pictures with a link to the content, and if you click it and aren't authenticated, you're bounced to the login page. The catch is, if you aren't logged in, you can't even see that content.

Using the SecurityDisabler is an easy solution, but we want that content to be editable in experience editor as well. We usually use GlassView over the controller rendering, so perhaps one solution is to fill the model via a controller rendering and wrap the get call in SecurityDisabler. What I was wondering if there was a way using GlassView to call the model with SecurityDisabler functionality in it, a switch or option in the model setup perhaps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A colleague worked this out, by wrapping a SecurityDisabler using statement around the foreach loop of the content we wanted to retrieve in the view.